# JAX-WS client in websphere with custom ssl socket factory

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I have JAX-WS generate client proxys that need to connect using HTTPS. The certificate handling needs to be custom since we store the certs in a database instead.

I have a working version for the SUN JAXWS implementation, but now I need to have the same client code working in WebSphere 7.0.

Unfortunately the JAX-WS standard is a little weak in this regard. It is an implementation specific procedure on how to do this and in case of WebSphere I do not find a lot of information.

I noticed that Axis2 seems to be used but I find nothing usefull on how to set up the custom handshaking I have working in the SUN implementation.

Comment: Nobody ? What a shame :-)
I create a bug report on WebSphere and got promoted to level 3. But I am still waiting for almost a month now, I guess they fired the person who wrote the stupid hacks to disable the standard Axis2 and HTTPClient solution ?

Comment: 11 years later. Still no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not even IBM can help me. So I just implemented my own JAX-WS -> SOAP conversion. That took 2 days and supports everything I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default SSLSocketFactory for the HttpsURLConnection using the static method setDefaultSSLSocketFactory. This will then be the socket factory for al new instaces of HttpsURLConnection. We got this working in an SE application, I think it would work with Axis too.